# Upload JSON file from HTML input tag rather than hard coding the file path in react

Tags: reactjs

I have wasted a lot of time in resolving the issue with uploading JSON file through HTML input tag rather than using the 'import' & hard coding the JSON file path in react but has got no success. This is required in my project where we are rendering a lot of different files and then converting to excel and it will be easy for us to simply choose the file using the input tag and then render it. here is my example code.

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
    // Don't want to hard ocde it like this => import data from "./data/1records.json";
    
    
    class Invoices extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            rows: []
        }
      }

      fileHandler = (event) => {
        let records = event.target.files[0];
        this.setState({
            rows: records.rows,
        });              
        console.log(records);
      }
    
      render() {

        const data = this.state.rows;

        return (
          <div className="container-fluid" style={{ backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7' }}>
            <input type="file" onChange={this.fileHandler.bind(this)} style={{"padding":"10px"}} />
            <ul>
              {data.map((rec) => (
                 <>
                   <li><strong>First Name: </strong>{rec.firstName} <strong>Last name </strong>{rec.lastName} <strong>Age: </strong>{rec.age}</li>
                 </>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default Invoices;
```

For some reason I'm not able to store the file data in the `state` successfully. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: please check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-flower-1l7kt4?file=/src/App.js) sandbox and modify accordingly. I tested this with the users JSON from [here](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users).

Comment: hi @ServeshChaturvedi, Thanks heaps for helping me out. It did helped me and I have resolved the issue. Many thanks for your kind efforts :-)